# DT shows table with a slider but not the whole table in dashboard and shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dashboard, dt, flexdashboard

I am using R in RStudio, with `DT`, `flexdashboard`, and `Shiny`. Since the recent update, tables in `DT::datatable` are not showing the whole table in the rendered output.

For example,

```
datatable(iris, options = list(buttons='excel',
                          autoWidth = TRUE, 
                          pageLength = 50,
                          fixedHeader = TRUE))
```

will show the whole table if the output is a simple markdown file, but if you use these codes in a dashboard or a shiny, the table automatically got a slider for each page. Check here:
https://zsnv7j-quan-cui.shinyapps.io/dashboard/

How can I get the dashboard and shiny to show the complete table (in this case, 50 rows without the slider on the right)? Thank you in advance.

Comment: autoWidth is part of the options argument. Try`options = list(autoWidth = TRUE)`  instead.